# E-Mail gets rejected for no reason, whatsoever

Tags: email

My mom can't accomplish this simple task: of sending recent photos to her best friend via email, because everytime it gets rejected. And I am more curious of why it would happen instead of begging for fix, because it isn't a big deal, we can always share those photos with her in Google Drive or via any removable media device of some sort.

So the actual problem is that when she sends blank e-mail with only photos attached (straight photos, no zips) to her's best friend, it gets instantly rejected with following message:

```
Your message was automatically rejected by Sieve, a mail
filtering language.

The following reason was given:
```

with header `Automatically rejected mail` from `Mail Sieve Subsystem`. And then it has the original message as an attachement at the end. What's interesting is that they're both on the same mail-server `http://mail.inbox.lv/`. I personally use Gmail and I remember that I couldn't send emails to "inbox.lv" users due some incompatibility but now it's seems to be working.

The question is: What's happening here?

**Edit:**
I used my old account at inbox.lv to send one photo to my mom and it worked as it should. Huh!?

**Edit 2:**
Mom sent those photos to my old account at inbox.lv and I received them. Why?

**Edit 3:**
Recipient received the same email with photos but only from my account. That means something is wrong with my mothers account?

Comment: Is your mom able to send image attachments to your Gmail ID?

Comment: @jjk_charles Will try.

Comment: @jjk_charles Well, `message size exceeds the size limit`. So that's that.

Comment: That is exactly what I suspected it to be!

Comment: @jjk_charles I can receive the pictures at my old account. I call shenanigans on this one.

Comment: As for your second edit, it is possible that the recipient's mail box is full, which should have been the reason, but the response you received might not have clear enough!

Comment: @jjk_charles Just checked. Recipient's mail box has only 6% of 20 GB used. Those pictures all together are below 30 MB in size while it's possible to send attachements of total 35 MB.

Comment: Are both users using the same provider?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, they are.

Comment: Doesn't simply entering some text in the email body solve this, and hence answer your question?

Comment: @Arjan I currently cannot try that. But why I was able to send the photos from my account without any text included?

Comment: _"she sends blank e-mail with only photos attached"_ That's a massive red flag for a spam filter, surely?

Comment: [Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_%28mail_filtering_language%29) is a filtering language defined in [RFC 5228](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5228). Typically, this would mean that the recipient has set -perhaps inadvertedly- a rule that rejects it. I would expect it to be related to the empty body, but given that it works from your account, there seems to be _something else_. Check the recipient rules.